# Is there any advantage in C++ using output parameters?

Tags: c++, embedded, documentation

**Background**

I'm trying to write some documentation which can be used by embedded C++ developers (like anybody). In the documentation I state the following:

Don’t use output parameters because:

1. They require documentation for much of their behaviour; For example is nullptr valid? What happens if the function fails, is the value changed? Does the function acquire resources, if it does who releases them?
2. In most cases std::optional can be used instead.
3. Multiple output parameters can should be handled with std::tuple or a struct.

I've seen usages of output parameters in almost every major API I've used but I believe it is mainly related to legacy.

**Question**

What are valid reasons that output parameters would still be used in modern C++?

Have I missed any reasons not to use output parameters?

---

I might add that output parameters are optimised less, but I only have small examples of this and haven't studied it long enough to be sure. Example : https://godbolt.org/z/bn89pO

---

**Edit**
Changed rule to "Avoid where possible use of output parameters because:"

Comment: Output parameters are definitely beneficial if you are a Pascal programmer, which doesn't have return values (other than primitives).

Comment: Look at the *stream* objects. They often use output parameters for things like `in >> var;` and the like. I also find them convenient for writing parsers. And `std::optional` works well for some things, but not everything. I would probably recommend returning a value as the first design choice to consider but I would not rule out others entirely. I think this question is really too broad and too subject to opinion tbh.

Comment: I do want to eliminate opinion where possible. 
Evidence based responses are what I'm looking for.

Comment: The `STL` also uses *output iterators* for some *algorithms*. It is very efficient compared with returning an output container. However it is easier to reason on code that returns values and prove correctness. Swings and roundabouts.

Comment: Interesting, do you have a reference to an implementation that mutates its parameter?

Comment: I have one example so far, std::swap most certainly does. 
Thats certainly more convieniet. I'll have to write "prefer" in relation to the rule.

Comment: `STL` *output iterators* are not exactly the same as your asking for I suppose as they don't change the parameter itself, but the they write to an external object through that parameter.

Comment: Its a decent point though, certainly makes the language in my document more difficult. It could be considered an "output parameter" so I agree with you.

Comment: `std::regex_replace` uses both approaches - *output iterator* **or** *returned container* so you can choose between efficiency or ease of use.

Comment: Thanks! I deleted my last comment, I misread your comment.

Comment: I suppose it boils down to the caller managing the resources or the called function creating it. If the caller does it, efficiencies can be gained in tight loops because you don't have to create a new object each time - you can reuse the output variable. But it can be less safe too. Sometimes I write an output parameter version and a returned value version of the same function so I can choose which is appropriate. The general consensus among the experts seems to be to try to return objects if possible. Compilers optimize that scenario quite well.

Comment: To be honest I have literally spent decades trying to figure out these types of trade-offs. Still looking for that silver bullet.

Comment: Depending on whether you count it, you could consider error codes in `std::filesystem`.

Comment: The CppCoreGuidelines may be of interest to you. Particularly the functions section. Specifically [F20](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rf-out) is relevant to this. https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#f-functions

Comment: I definately count it. std::filesystem uses overloads to optionally include the error code parameter. Interesting pattern, I wouldn't have used it. I wonder why they selected that methodoligy.

Comment: @Galik I am referencing that document for most of the work I'm doing. I did miss that section thankyou!

Comment: Most embedded systems don't use file systems in the first place, so I'm not quite sure what this debate is all about...

Comment: There is no debate. Its an example of use in a well accepted library (not in embedded though...). Its a pattern that is clearly used. What is still ambigious is why you couldn't embedded the error code in the result. Most embedded software doesn't use filesystem or regex or even streams. I'm considering putting together a version of Optional that instead of storing a bool for whether it is valid stores an enum class that MUST contain Enum::Valid it could behave identically to std::optional with error codes.

Comment: @chris In contrast, `to_chars` returns `[ptr, ec]`.

Comment: @L. F. to_chars in my opinion has an excellent output style!

Comment: There is a strangeness to to_chars though.Its not iterator based; and,
It does manipulate the range as sort of an output parameter.